# NextJS fails to parse tailwind css

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, plesk

I've setup a react app (via create-react-app), which I deployed via Plesk (which I don't know much, but I have to use that...), but it seems nextjs doesn't understand tailwind css. All is fine locally.

Here's the error I get:
I have the following error message:

```
Server Error

ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-flight-css-loader.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> @tailwind base;
| @tailwind components;
| @tailwind utilities;
```

tailwind.conf.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

next.conf.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

postcss.conf.js

```
const { join } = require('path');

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {
        config: join(__dirname, 'tailwind.config.js'),
    },
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

From what I've seen googling around, this could be a webpack problem, but I don't have any config file...

Any idea?

(I was wondering if using node 16.20.1 could be an issue?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue, actually had to deploy in production mode.

Shortly:

next.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
  output: 'standalone',
}
```

Then move the `.next/standalone` folder to plesk and set nodejs to use `server.js` as starting binary.
You might also need to copy the `public` and `.next/static` folders in app root folder.